# How do I install this add-on?

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to install this addon but can't:
https://sods-blender-plugins.googlecode.com/files/io_import_z64_v4.rar
I just installed Blender 2.7.5, I was using 2.7.2 previously.
I have placed it into the addons folder and tried to install using file several times.
it says there's an unexpected EOF when parsing, ast.parse can't read it,  and addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad info. 
Blender's console:

[image]

I've done everything I can to try to figure out how to get the addon to work and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you activate it under the "add-ons"-tab in your user preferences?

Comment: I was unable to activate it since it didn't show up in that tab. I also tried pressing install using file, as noted in my post.

Comment: Going to the home page, and clicking on the [issues tab](https://code.google.com/p/sods-blender-plugins/issues/list) for the addon, I see that a similar issue was reported more than a year ago, but that no further information has been posted to the google site.

Comment: the file: http://www.pasteall.org/59458/python

Comment: Looks like you have two installs that may be conflicting. In the screenshot you have `2.75/scripts/addons/io_import_z64.py` as well as `2.75/scripts/addons_contrib/io_import_z64.py`

Answer (score 2):

you will have to edit the file yourself. You can delete the empty line between "category" and "anim stuff", it seems to trip up the `bl_info` parsing:

```
bl_info = {
   "name": "Zelda64 Importer",
   "author": "SoulofDeity",
   "blender": (2, 6, 0),
   "location": "File > Import-Export",
   "description": "Import Zelda64",
   "warning": "",
   "wiki_url": "https://code.google.com/p/sods-blender-plugins/",
   "tracker_url": "https://code.google.com/p/sods-blender-plugins/",
   "support": 'COMMUNITY',
   "category": "Import-Export",
   "Anim stuff": "RodLima http://www.facebook.com/rod.lima.96?ref=tn_tnmn"
}
```

Comment: its not actually the Anim stuff line that does it. There is a bad Binary character in the whitespace between the end of the line before, and the start of "anim stuff" delete the blank line fixes it.

Comment: yeah, there's all kinds of indentation issues with that file.